# Attribute error creating a column of NER labels

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to create columns in a dataframe that show the entities and labels from a spaCy model, so far by entering the following code I can produce a column of entities:

```
df['new_col'] = df['Combined'].apply(lambda x: list(ner_model(x).ents))
```

However, if I try the same for labels:

```
#df['new_col1'] = df['Combined'].apply(lambda x: list(nlp(x).label_))
```

I get 'AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.doc.Doc' object has no attribute 'label_''

I suspect I might have to iterate over individual tokens but I am not sure how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this

```
df['new_col1'] = df['Combined'].apply(lambda x: [ent.label_ for ent in nlp(x).ents])
```

The output of `nlp(x)` is a `Doc` object and there is no `label` attribute on the `Doc` object (as is explicitly stated in the error you get). You need the labels of the entities on the `Doc` object which is why you need to iterate over `nlp(x).ents` and get the `label_` of each entity.